# gprof error: profile file has unsupported version

Tags: linux, gprof

I am trying to profile a shared library but there is an error when I invoke gprof:

```
    $ export LD_PROFILE=libMy.so
    $ ./a.out
    $ gprof -q libMy.so /var/tmp/libMy.so.profile
    gprof: file /var/tmp/libMy.so.profile has unsupported version 131071
```

Shared library was compiled with -ggdb -pg flags.

gcc version 4.2.1, gprof version 2.20, linux 2.6.22

Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used glibc profiling, but as far as I can tell, the generated `.profile` file is not in the format `gprof` expects. Try [sprof](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sprof) instead.